# Windows 7 taskbar icon not displayed in .net 3.5 application

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-7, icons, taskbar

My application is in .net 3.5 its icon appears fine on the Windows 7 taskbar when I am running the application. But, when I pin my application to the taskbar, the icon dispappears and is replaced with the default windows "no icon" image. I tried making a 48 bit image for my .ico but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icon you're seeing when the application is not pinned is the window's icon. When it's pinned, the application's icon is used instead. Go to the project's properties and set an icon in the Application tab (this should of course be the same icon used for the main window to avoid any confusion).

Comment: This is backwards! (in VS 2008, anyway). The Main Form's icon is shown on the taskbar. If the main form's icon is not specified, the default icon is shown on the task bar. The app's icon is shown in Windows Explorer. Nevertheless, this clue helped me discover why my apps were all showing a default icons on the taskbar - I had not specified an icon for the main form.

Comment: TIP: I just found out that adding additional resolution images to an .ico file doesn't take effect until you re-import the icon resource to both the form and the app.  These are apparently embedded resources.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed:
If you pin an app that is started from within visual studio the "empty" icon is used always, because the link is set to "AppName.vshost.exe" executable.